# Подставить вместо звездочек цифры из промежутка от 1 до 9. Числа не должны повторяться. **** / *** = **

Tags: c#

Результат вывода, который должен быть:

```
4396 / 157 = 28
5346 / 198 = 27
5346 / 297 = 18
5796 / 138 = 42
5796 / 483 = 12
7254 / 186 = 39
7632 / 159 = 48
```

Вроде должен работать, но не выводит все возможные варианты.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApp16
 {
 class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int r = 0;
        for(int i = 1000; i < 9999; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 111; j < 999; j++)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    int k = i / j;
                    if((k > 9) & (k < 100) & (Func1(i, j, k)))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i + " / " + j + " = " + k);
                        r++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Read();

        Console.WriteLine("sum = " + r);
        }
        protected static bool Func1(int i, int j, int k)
        {
        int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        bool Func1 = false;

        while (i != 0)
        {
            if (array[i % 10] > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            i += array[i % 10];
            i /= 10;
        }

        while (j != 0)
        {
            if (array[j % 10] > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            j += array[j % 10];
            j /= 10;
        }

        while (k != 0)
        {
            if (array[k % 10] > 0)
            {
                break;
            } 
            k += array[k % 10];
            k /= 10;
        }
        Func1 = true;
        return Func1;
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Поясните, как работает `Func1` ?

Comment: В коде реально такое выравнивание или это после копирования получилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исключить повторы цифр, начальные значения массива должны быть нулевыми.

А встретили цифру - соответствующий элемент массива пометить надо, а не что попало менять.

Кроме того, логика формирования результата функции была неверной, при повторе цифры  надо немедленно выходить из функции, а не следующий цикл запускать.

Вот изменения для того, чтобы программа заработала (аналогично для j,k).

*Об эффективности полного перебора не будем  уж говорить.

Простейшее: если перебирать k и j, то будет в 100 раз быстрее*

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        while (i != 0)
        {
            if (array[i % 10] > 0)
                return false;
            array[i % 10] += 1;
            i /= 10;
        }
```